# Why is the value prefixed with "Elixir."?

Tags: module, elixir, alias

Working with maps provide me with an unexpected outcome in VS Code: The expected outcome, when picking a property out of the maps, is prefixed with
"Elixir.", followed by the expected outcome.

I downloaded VS Code and Elixir versions as recently as 20 days ago. My OS is Windows 11.

I do not prefer the shortcut to iex (as in the "interactive mode"). I fail the correct syntax and the understanding.

I changed the name of the map, altered the keys and values into number and re-typed the map, as well as the instruction – but the prefix, "Elixir.", remains.

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html#alias):

> Note: All modules defined in Elixir are defined inside the main Elixir
> namespace, such as Elixir.String. However, for convenience, you can
> omit “Elixir.” when referencing them.

On p. 32, "Elixir in Action" introduces atoms.  The first way to create an atom is like this:

```
:dog
```

You cannot use just any characters when you create an atom like that, but you can use any characters if you use quotes, giving you a second way to create atoms:

```
:"wag the dog!"
```

A third way to create an atom is by starting the name with a capital letter:

```
AnAtom
```

In iex:

```
iex(3)> is_atom(AnAtom)   
true
```

"Elixir in Action" says that `AnAtom` is actually an `alias` (you can read about alias's at the link in the first sentence at the top of this answer).  `AnAtom` is considered an alias because when you compile your code, `AnAtom` is replaced by `:"Elixir.AnAtom"`.  In iex:

```
iex(4)> AnAtom == :"Elixir.AnAtom"
true
```

That means that module names are atoms, e.g.

```
defmodule MyFunctions do
  def do_stuff
    IO.puts "hello"
  end
end
```

Whether you knew it or not, you created a map with values that are atoms:

```
person = %{
   :Daughter => Judith
   
   ...
   ...
}
```

`Judith` creates an atom.  And, as "Elixir in Action" says, `Judith` is an alias for the atom `:"Elixir.Judith"`.

Practically, I would suggest that you never write code like that:

```
person = %{
   :Daughter => Judith
   
   ...
   ...
}
```

Most people would write the code like this:

```
person = %{

    daughter: "Judith",
    ...

}
```

The reason atoms are used for keys in maps is because it is very efficient to compare atoms, where it is relatively inefficient to compare strings, which must be compared character by character.

In conclusion, while the output in VS Code is correct, it is useless, unneeded information--see the same output in iex, for example.

> I do not prefer the shortcut to iex. As in the "interactive mode" I
> fail the correct syntax and the understanding.

The way I write programs is: I use the editor of my choice (vim, VS Code, etc) to create files, like my_functions.ex.  When I am done coding, I save the file.  I have a terminal window open below my editor, where I have cd'ed into the same directory as my file.  After I save the file in the editor, I compile the file using my terminal window, e.g.:

```
$ iex my_functions.ex
```

and I call the functions in iex.  Then, I go back to editing the code in my editor to correct errors or write more code.  I never write code in iex.

By the way, what plugin are you using to execute your code in VS Code?

Comment: Installed & plugins: VSCode 1.77.3, VS BuildTools PS 7.4, Elixir 14.4, Erlang OTP-25.3, main-otp 25, Outstand ElixirLS 4.175, code-runner, Credo [ElixirLinter], GitHub, Elixir Formatter.

Answer (score 0):

That's by design from the language and interop with erlang.

> What’s happening here is subtle. Internally, module names are just atoms. When you write a name starting with an uppercase letter, such as IO, Elixir converts it internally into an atom called Elixir.IO.

You can read more [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/programming-elixir/9781680500530/f_0060.html)

Answer (score 0):

Stand-alone words that begin with an upper case letter in Elixir are [aliases](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/syntax-reference.html#aliases) that refer to module names. They are automatically prefixed with `Elixir.`:

```elixir
iex> to_string Utrecht
Elixir.Utrecht
iex> Utrecht == :"Elixir.Utrecht"
true
```

What you should do instead is use `:` to designate that you want to define your own atom, not an alias:

```elixir
iex> to_string :Utrecht
"Utrecht"
iex> :Utrecht == :"Elixir.Utrecht"
false
```

Or use a string:

```elixir
iex> "Utrecht"
"Utrecht"
```